# How to do single sign-on with PHP?

Tags: php

Eg: Gmail, Orkut, Wava and feedburner login access using single google account.

Comment: Your question is way too general. I tried to give my best answer below, but I'm sure that I'm not the only one wishing you would be more specific with what you actually want.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Your question is too unspecific to give a precise answer. If you're trying to let users log in to your website using Google accounts, it's documented [here](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/GettingStarted.html).

On the other hand, if you're trying to let your users sign in to several websites you control with one account, here's how you can do it:

Make all login links on your sites point to a centralized login page, but include information about where the user came from in the link. For example:

```
<a href='http://login.example.com/login.php?source=my.other.site.com/foo/bar'>log in!!</a>
```

Then, once the user has logged in successfully, you redirect the user back to the original site while passing along whatever information you need about the authenticated user.

However, you also need to make sure that people can't just circumvent your authentication mechanism by adding the necessary authentication parameters to the URL. This can be done by including a signature in the form of an HMAC-SHA-256 of the parameters plus a secret that's stored on both login server and the originating site. (Preferably this key should be different for each site using your SSO system.)

```
<?php
$MySecretKey = 'Nobody Will Ever Guess This!!';

// Generate signature from authentication info + secret key
$sig = hash(
    'sha256',
     $user->id . $user->email,
     $MySecretKey
);

// Make sure we're redirecting somewhere safe
$source = parse_url($_GET['source']);
if(in_array($source->host, $list_of_safe_hosts))
  $target = 'http://'.$source->host.$source->path;

// Send the authenticated user back to the originating site
header('Location: '.$target.'?'.
    'user_id='.$user->id.
    '&user_email='.urlencode($user->email).
    '&sig='.$sig);
?>
```

Then, in the originating site, if the signature matches the user is already logged in. Store the info about the logged in user in session variables (not a cookie):

```
<?php
$MySecretKey = 'Nobody Will Ever Guess This!!';

// Set not logged in by default
$user_id = 0;
$user_email = '';

if(intval($_GET['user_id']) && !$_SESSION['user_id']) // Someone trying to log in?
{
  // See if they have the right signature
  if (hash_equals(hash('sha256', intval($_GET['user_id']).$_GET['user_email'], $MySecretKey), $sig)) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = intval($_GET['user_id']);
    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $_GET['user_email'];
  }
}

?>
```

Note that I'm using a function added in PHP 5.6: [`hash_equals`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php). If you're on lower than 5.6, you can use this substitute function which implements a [timing-safe comparison](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/11/its-all-about-time.html) function using [double HMAC verification](https://www.isecpartners.com/blog/2011/february/double-hmac-verification.aspx):

```
function hash_equals($a, $b) {
    $key = mcrypt_create_iv(128, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    return hash_hmac('sha512', $a, $key) === hash_hmac('sha512', $b, $key);
}
```

This is obviously a very crude implementation, but it should be a decent starting point.

Comment: If it is "obviously very crude" it would be nice if you name the current security flaws and how a real implementation should fix that. Like: the problem of a network-sniffed $sig, multiple logins with same account and more.

Comment: I actually meant it's crude in the sense that I wrote the code here without any testing. Considering the complete lack of detail in the original question, I think my answer went beyond what could be expected. That said, yes, the issues you point out are certainly valid.

Comment: $MySecretKey = 'Nobody Will Ever Guess This!!'; if it is a constant, some one can observe and know that every time we are attaching some same code at end.  then how it is  secure?.

Comment: @aparna The secret itself is never seen by the client, it's only used to generate an MD5 hash that can't be predicted without knowing the secret. Also, it doesn't necessarily need to be constant, but both servers need to be able to determine what the secret should be for any particular login attempt, without looking at anything that's included in the transmission.

Comment: [random.org](http://www.random.org/strings/?num=1&len=20&digits=on&upperalpha=on&loweralpha=on&format=html&rnd=new) gives about 120 bits of randomness for a secret key. English language entropy is difficult to estimate - but I feel better not using pattern matching wetware for random data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick start. I guess, if I want to improve that, then I could remove the $MySecretKey from the originating site and instead add additional background API call from the originating site to the SSO central to verify that the session is still valid, and then on the SSO central site I could make the $sig more random using some random number or time(). It should protect me from network sniffing (at least for one session length). But it seems we are getting into full-feature SSO territory here with service tickets and whatnot.

Answer (score 8):

If you are wanting a cross-site central login system, I would recommend something like [OpenID](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/#php). You could run your own server, and then have only one login for multiple sites.

Comment: +1 this is the solution that uses SO.

Comment: +1 for Open Id! For the UI, there is a jQuery plugin you can use, which smoothes out the slight differences in implementation between providors... http://plugins.jquery.com/project/simpleopenid - there is a PHP sample on the OpenID website you can use along with this script.

Comment: I know that stackoverflow themeselves uses OpenID to track ppl's sign-ins cross-domain.

Comment: [Single sign-on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) concept is different from [OpenId](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID).

Comment: different how Mahesh?

Comment: @Maruccio: Different in that with SSO, you log in once -- hence the name.  OpenID lets you use the same ID on multiple sites, but that doesn't mean you're logged in to them all when you log in to one.

Comment: you can try also Zend OpenID [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.openid.html)

Answer (score 3):

Have one central registry for authenticated users.

All applications access this parent to get authentication.

Cross domain cookies can be done with special links with a nonce, and a new cookie is created on the new domain if the nonce matches a valid token from the parent.

Comment: Can you suggest me some tutorial links http://www.pubcookie.org/