# GET-request to other domain to login at other domain via cUrl

Tags: php, session, authentication, curl, cross-domain

I'm desperate! I'm trying to connect a file server and a databaseserver.
First both were one, but now we've decided to seperate them due to high server requests.
 

www.domain.ext => server A
files.domain.ext => server B

At server A, we have our CMS which authenticates the user.

At server B, we have a lot of directories with images/documents inside, which can be retrieved like this:
http://files.domain.ext/user/{username}/filename.jpg.
Now, we have to know at server B which user has been logged in at server A, to get the right username.

At first we've tried to echo the session data in a specific file and to read that via cUrl. This seemed to be impossible, because we couldn't access the session which was set at server A and the result was always "401 Not authenticated". Even though the session domain was set to ".domain.ext" and CORS-headers were sent.

Now, when a user is logging in at server A, we send a cUrl GET-request to a file at server B with a combination of "unique" userdata.
The file at server B receives the userdata and is going to authenticate for himself. If the userdata matches, a session is created at server B and everything should work fine.

[image: Valid XHTML]
.

The problem is that when I requests the file at server B with the userdata by browsing to the URL, I'm getting logged in and everything works fine.
But when I execute the cUrl-request to the same URL, the session at server B stays empty.

My goal is to include an iframe in the CMS at server A to show the files for a specific user from server B.
I can't get the filemanager at server A for he needs the physical files.

What options do I have?

Comment: just because you logged in via your browser doesn't mean that curl will magically pick up on the cookie that your browser received. server B is going to see those requests are completely separate/unique.

Comment: Have you setup your CURL requests to accept and store cookies and then send them on any subsequent calls?

Comment: best solution for you is single sign on (SSO)

Comment: @MarcB: It should be the other way around. The browser has to "magically" pick-up the cookie which has been set in the cUrl-request. So cUrl sends my credentials to the other server and creates a session cookie without being noticed by the end user. When the CMS includes the url of server B in an iframe, the user has to access only his own images. We use Moxiemanager as front-end for the images.

Comment: @DaveGill: There are no subsequent calls. If it was an api, there should be subsequent calls. The goal is to create a login session at another server to be used when including an iframe with content from the other server.

Comment: @eavuursteen: not possible. serverA cannot set a cookie as originating at serverB, or vice versa. that'd be an incredibly NASTY security problem, e.g. nastyhackers.ru being able to access/set cookies for yourbank.com, type thing. there's plenty of SSO options available, don't try to build your own.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on), it is more stable solution for you

you can google it or check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5176376/3615630) maybe help