# Give same login details to 2 different websites

Tags: php, session

i have one website called www.example.com and i have another website www.example.com/project

So now i have two different logins for both.so i gave one button in super admin dashboard  called **upload** in my portal (www.example.com/project) when i click on the button it has to go to www.example.com

In my users table i have one column called idnumber there i am storing the userlevel access so in my project portal idnumber '3' means super admin and in www.example.com portal '3' is treated as guest and '1' is treated as super admin.in my project portal 1 is treated as user.

when i try to use same login in my portal it is logged in as user.

i want to give the same login details for both applications.

Can anyone tell me how to do that..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33324169/same-login-on-2-websites (this should answer your question)

Comment: in their case it is different database but in my case same database and same table with same column

Comment: @Aurelien can you please give me another way..