# How to login user in both WordPress and custom website?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have word-press eCommerce website which made with Woo-commerce plugin. I have developed a membership site for my customers who buy things in my web-store. I am maintaining separate user table in my database. Username is same in both word-press wp-user table and mine. I would like to login the user in both my membership area as well as in word-press, So that I can fetch data from word-press (Like printing receipt ect). It should happen when users log-into my custom membership. My Custom membership has been developed using php. Both Wordpress and custom Membership are under the same domain. We can use wordpress functions in custom membership also.

Thanks

Comment: Use WordPress login session for any custom site also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you Go, You can login wordpress user while loginto custom page.

```
  $user = get_user_by( 'email', "username@domain.com" );
    if( $user ) {
        wp_set_current_user( $user->id, $user->user_login );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->id );
        do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The Best Solution for your problem is SSO (Single Sign on). Single sign-on (SSO) is a property of access control of multiple related, but independent software systems.

SSO (Single Sign On) means that when a user logs in to one application he will be "automatically" signed in to every other application, regardless of the platform, technology and domain.

For example, Google implements SSO for their products: Gmail, YouTube, Analytics, etc. When you turn on your computer and access Gmail, you login for the first time. Then, if you go to YouTube you won't be prompted for credentials again.

The way this works is by means of a "central service" (in the case of Google this is https://accounts.google.com). When you login for the first time a cookie gets created on this central service. Then, when you try to access the second application, you get redirected to the central service, but since you already have a cookie, you get redirected to the app directly with a token, which means you're already logged in.

WordPress SSO Plug-ins - https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/single-sign-on

If your Custom Website is PHP based see the solution here - [How to do single sign-on with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062569/how-to-do-single-sign-on-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to continue with your version, and not to try a single sing on as adviced before, what you need to do is "log the user" at the same time in every site that you own.

This idea is not the best, but I am assuming that your members area is inside wordpress, so the site should be the same. If this is not the case, single sign on is the best option for you.

Comment: Thank you. I have found the solution. Its simple. I am not asking for external website login. The custom membersship and wordpress both are in the same domain.

Comment: Please can you explain how to fix this issues, i am having the same problem now