# How do I share sessions between two codeigniter apps............?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have two codeingiter applications: 'A' and 'B' 
I log into app 'A' and then do some stuff and for some functionality, I have to redirect to app 'B'
I send a simple 'user_id' set in the session for further processing in app 'B'
Now I don't want to log into app B again.
I was just wondering how would one achieve that...? and No I cannot merge the two.

These two apps are on the same server.

I Tried to do it using sessions but the session data erases out when redirecting

I just want to know where to start looking because nobody has addressed this issue

I am currently doing it using curl but it is going to take a heck of a lot of modifications so just wondering if you guys have any better solution..........

Comment: how about SSO ? - take a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062569/how-to-do-single-sign-on-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point session path to same directory in both applications:

> $config['sess_save_path'] = 'path_of_session_directory'

you can change that in [this file](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L377).

And make sure your cookie domain is the same in both applications.

Also, just to make this answer a little more complete, take a look at [sticky sessions](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/900933) in case you ever want to do that in separate servers.